# Dihedral group of a square $D_4$

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups

Prove that in the $D_4$ a square's symmetry group each element can be uniquely written as $r^i s^j$, $i =1,2,3, \ \ j=0,1$, where $r$ is a rotation by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ around the centre of the square, and $s$ is a symmetry around one of the axes, and then write the element as $sr^2s^{-1}r^{-1}s^3r^5.$

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to find out what $sr^2s^{-1}r^{-1}s^3r^5$ you can just take an actual square and do that to it, and write out what you get at the end.

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem** $rs = sr^{-1}$.
*proof*: $$rs(x,y) = r(-x,y) = (-y,-x)$$ and $$sr^{-1}(x,y) = s(y,-x) = (-y,-x).$$

Now we can use this result, for example $$\begin{array}{rcl}
&& sr^2s^{-1}r^{-1}s^3r^5 \\
&=& ss^{-1} r^{-2} r^{-1} s^3 r^{5} \\
&=& r^{-3} s s s r^{5} \\
&=& s r^{3} s s r^{5} \\
&=& s s r^{-3} s r^{5} \\
&=& s s s r^{3} r^{5} \\
&=& s^{3} r^{8} \\
&=& s
\end{array}$$

Comment: Do I do it on a picture or are there any "formulas" for reflection and rotation? If we have a point $z$ on a plane then $s(z)=\bar{z}$. Is there a similar way to describe rotation?

Comment: yes $r(x,y) = (-y,x)$

Comment: Right, the angle is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I sill don't know how to solve the problem. Could you help me a little more?

Comment: @Hagrid, I added more, does this help?

Comment: Thank you. How can I justify the uniqueness of the representation of any element of D4?

Comment: @Hagrid, that's a very good question. You can label the 4 corners of a square $$(A,B,C,D) = ((1,1),(-1,1),(-1,-1),(1,-1))$$ then note that $G = \langle r, s \rangle$ has an orbit of size 8 on that (this certainly implies the fact I used implicitly that if $g(x,y) = g'(x,y)$ for all $x,y$ then $g=g'$). You may prove it quicker depending on the definition of $D_4$.

Comment: Those 8 elements are $r, \ r^2, \ r^3, \ r^4=id, \ sr, \ sr^2, \ sr^3, \ sr^4=s$, is that right? But I fail to see how to prove what you wrote in the brackets. As to the definition of $D_4$, it's a group of symmetries of a regular polygon, with the operation of composition.

Comment: @Hagrid, with that definition there is nothing to be proved, since r and s are exactly the functions we used in the proof. Under that def. this is just the fact that two functions equal everywhere are equal.

Comment: I don't understand that.

Comment: @Hagrid, why not?

Comment: Well, I see that $rs = sr^{-1}$ and this allows us to simplify compositions of operations. I know that the group of symmetries and rotations of a square around a fixed point has 8 elements as listed above. What I don't see is how that proves uniqueness of the representation mentioned above.

Comment: @Hagrid, can you state formally what you mean by uniqueness of the representation? (which representation etc.)

Comment: By uniqueness of the representation I mean that any sequence of operations of reflection and rotation can be uniquely written in the form $r^is^j$ just as you did in your answer. My (possibly groundless) worry is how to justify that we will indeed get one $r^is^j$ for each $r^as^br^cs^d...$.

Comment: @Hagrid, Oh right! by repeatedly using the theorem we can turn anything (like $r^a s^b r^c s^d$) into the form $s^y r^{x}$ and they are equal. Now since $s^{2}=1$ and $r^{4}=1$ you can reduce these further to $s^{y'} r^{x'}$  with $0 \le y' < 2$ and $0 \le x' < 4$. Since there are 8 such elements and every element of the group may be written in this way they are all distinct.

Comment: Great, I understand it now. Thanks a lot for all your help, and patience!